# How do I get a CSS pseudo selector act on an element？

Tags: javascript, html, css, selenium, hover

I want to test if an element that is not visible to the user on webpage can be displayed by hover.So I need to find all pseduo selecotrs act on it.

```
.top ul li:hover ul{
    display: block;
}
```

When I visit a "ul" tag or a "a" tag included by "ul", how can I know if it is influenced by this pseduo selecotrs?
Is there any other way to detect if it can be displayed by hover?

Comment: there isn't really a way to do this. Why do you need to know this?

Comment: Some secondary menus is realized by hover，these menus cannot be accessed by a blind， I want to find out these code.However, many tags just are just used for eso or other purpose，it is no need to make blind access.I can't differentiate them

Comment: You should be able to find out which elements are affected by using the dev tools to simulate hover.

Comment: I see that you're talking about accessibility, perhaps have a look at https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/menus/flyout/. There are some tips on how to make the fly-out menu accessible for keyboard users etc.